# Repetition of \def commands

Tags: macros

Below is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{\alpha}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\a{\theta}

\newcommand\s{\alpha}
\newcommand\f{\beta}
\newcommand\s{\theta}

\begin{document}

Sample Text $\a$

\end{document}
```

My problem is I want to show error while compiling the document if I have multiple `\def` in same name, for example `\def\a` repeated twice, for `\newcommand` it shows error if mentioned twice, likewise I need for `\def` too, please guide,

Comment: `\def` is  a TeX primitive and very deliberately doesn't do any checks: why can you not stick to `\newcommand`?

Comment: @JosephWright problem is we don't code the Latex files, it is being coded somewhere, where we can't give instructions to them to use a specific commands, Is it possible to make it check??

Comment: @user52124: Do you want to have something like `\ifdef` from `etoolbox`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer just need a Error message when i compile the Tex using PDFLATEX

Comment: @user52124: I've posted an example.

Comment: You can not do this. If you redefine `\def` not to be the tex primitive, then you will break almost every latex command.

Comment: note `\a` is already defined in latex so if it did check you would get an error form the first shown `\def not the second. Similarly `\b` is already defined.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do this. If you redefine `\def` not to be the tex primitive, then you will break almost every latex command.

As an aside, note `\a` is already defined in latex so if it did check you would get an error form the first shown `\def` not the second. Similarly `\b` is already defined.

You mentioned that the latex is being coded by someone else, you should report it as an error in that coding. `\def` is not a latex command and should not be used in latex documents (despite its widespread use in latex package files)